# What is the different when we change the "Execute in new LUW" property in a procedure from False to True

Tags: procedure, genexus

I want to ask about this new property in procedure, can anyone give me an example of this property. I've read the information on the GeneXus wiki but I don't understand.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it is set to Execute in new LUW, another connection to the database is opened and a new DBMS transaction  is started in the database. You can commit and rollback on that object (or the ones called by it) and it won't affect the rest of your process.
It is used to perform commits in other tables and without losing the transactional integrity in the main process.